# How to handle major structural change in your code in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project which is under trunk in my SVN. I have been working on it for last 2 months and its in stable state. Now I want to completely change the way my code is organized or structured keeping the implementation of the business logic same. I also want to keep the current state of my code stored at some place. I have tags, branches and releases folder in my repository apart from trunk.

I want to know what is the best approach to handle this scenario. I am little worried because if I just create a tag for my old code than it will not create a complete copy but will create links to the code available in trunk which I eventually going to change completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to worry about this "links" subversion will **copy** your files into the tags folder.internally it does not duplicate these files, as they are already in your repository, but subversion tags are copys, not links.
Also keep in mind that the tag is pointing to a specific *revision* of your sourcecode, so even if you want to follow this link analogy, the link will always point to a revision and an **old revision will never change in subversion**.

So go ahead and change the source as you like, but create a tag before you start. In this way you can always go back.